# Counting problem, one to one solution trouble

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Working through this problem.  I think I understand when $p\lt$q but not when $p\le q$.

**Problem**: A and B are finite sets. $p=|A|\quad q=|B|$.  How many distinct one-to-one functions are there $A \rightarrow B$ if $p \le q$

With $p \lt q$, I think you'd have $p!\over(p-q)!$

$a(1)\quad a(2) \quad\quad\quad  a(3) \quad ... \quad a(p)$

$a(q) \quad a(q-1) \quad a(q-2) ... a(p-q) = a(q) \ast(q-1)\ast\ ... \ a(p-q) = qPp =$ $p!\over(p-q)! $

The additional equal portion has me thinking you consider both the case of $p<q$ as well as $p=q$

I'm not sure how to arrive at the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, let's say that $A = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, p\}$ and that $B = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, q\}$, where $p \leq q$.

A function $f: A \to B$ is determined by where each element of $A$ is mapped.  It is injective (one-to-one) if each element of $A$ is mapped to a different element of $B$.  We have to choose an image in $B$ for each element in $A$.

We have $q$ choices for $f(1)$.  Since $f(2) \neq f(1)$, we have $q - 1$ choices for $f(2)$.  Since $f(3)$ must differ from both $f(1)$ and $f(2)$, we have $q - 2$ choices for $f(3)$.  In general, we have $q - (k - 1) = q - k + 1$ choices for $f(k)$ since $k - 1$ elements of $B$ have already been selected.  Thus, the number of injective functions $f: A \to B$ is
$$q(q - 1)(q - 2) \cdots (q - p + 1) = \frac{q(q - 1)(q - 2) \cdots (q - p + 1)(q -  p)!}{(q - p)!} = \frac{q!}{(q - p)!}$$
In particular, if $q = p$, then the number of injective functions $f: A \to B$ is $q! = p!$.

To illustrate, let $A = \{1, 2\}$; let $B = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.  The number of injective functions $f: A \to B$ is $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ since there are four possible values for $f(1)$ and three possible output values for $f(2)$ since $f(2) \neq f(1)$.  Since $|A| = 2$ and $|B| = 4$, $p = 2$ and $q = 4$, so our formula yields
$$\frac{q!}{(q - p)!} = \frac{4!}{(4 - 2)!} = \frac{4!}{2!} = \frac{24}{2} = 12$$
as expected.

The $12$ injective functions $f_k: A \to B$ are defined by:

$$
\begin{array}{c c c}
k & f_k(1) & f_k(2)\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 2\\
2 & 1 & 3\\
3 & 1 & 4\\
4 & 2 & 1\\
5 & 2 & 3\\
6 & 2 & 4\\
7 & 3 & 1\\
8 & 3 & 2\\
9 & 3 & 4\\
10 & 4 & 1\\
11 & 4 & 2\\
12 & 4 & 3
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thank you @N. F. Taussig.   The answer then changes based on the two cases and not a joint solution.

Comment: @yaelmacks  Notice that if $p = q$, then $\frac{q!}{(q - p)!} = \frac{q!}{(q - q)!} = \frac{q!}{0!} = \frac{q!}{1} = q! = p!$.

Comment: Ahh, I see -- forgive me but I just realized an error in my post -- should be $p \le q$   I think though your post still stands with letters swapped.

Comment: Edited/corrected the original post.

Comment: When I answered your question, it said that $p \leq q$.  The answer I wrote is correct under that assumption.  I added an example to demonstrate that the formula I wrote works.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_p\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_q\}$. \
If p=q, then, there are q ways to map $a_1$ onto B, there are q-1 ways to map $a_2$ onto B because we have already mapped a point of A onto some point of B and by following this way, all the possible ways to map A by 1-1 to B are $$q\cdot (q-1)\cdots 2\cdot1=q!$$.
In fact, you are looking for the number of p permutations of q      elements.